# $watch for value change from inside angular directive when using isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find a way to watch for a changing value of a property in an object I am scoping my directive to and I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my directive code:

```
.directive('selectService', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      distribution: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(scope.distribution.name, function(newValue) {
        console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
      });
```

So say distribution at the time this gets run is something like this:

```
{ name: '', type: 'all' ... }
```

I want to $watch for when the property 'name' changes to have a value so that I can enable a select menu in my directive. Everything I've done seems to not work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use watch the normal way, provide a string representing property on the scope or a function that returns the value to be watched.

```
  scope.$watch('distribution.name', function(newValue) {
    console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
  });
```

for setting up deep watch on the object `distribution` set the third argument of watch to true.
When you provide `scope.distribution.name` as the first argument to the watch function, it will just set up watch on the value (at that time) of `scope.distribution.name` which is incorrect.

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.distribution = {};
}).directive('selectService', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        distribution: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("distribution.name", function(newValue) {
          console.log("Changed to " + newValue);
        });
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input ng-model="distribution.name">{{distribution.name}}
  <div select-service distribution="distribution"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have also tried this as well, and when I enter a value in the name input field which is outside the directive, the directive code has already run, and it never hits this watch expression again for some reason.

Comment: @jaredwilli watch will always run for the first time for dirty checking. your hsould not have that issue. DO you have a demo?\

Comment: Don't have a demo, the app i'm making is quite complex and replicating what i'm doing would be impossible unfortunately.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. See my demo. You need to throw in more context to your question then. Is your input inside something that creates a child scope? like ng-repeat/ng-if etc? Atleast show us full minimal relevant code.

Comment: I actually just realized I was working in the wrong file lol. Wtf. I am sorry, this thread is no longer needed cuz I now just do ng-if=distribution.name on my directive tag, so that it shows the directive only after there is a name value, so I dont need to do $watch at all, which turns out to be a better UX as well. Thanks for your help though!!